# Pandas stacked histogram from column of DataFrame by values of another column?

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

Let's say I have data like this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Foo | 5 |
| Bar | 46 |
| Baz | 100 |
| Foo | 10 |
| ... | ... |

I'm trying to create a stacked histogram from a pandas DataFrame that stacks the series obtained by grouping by Column A the values of Column B.

I used `pd.hist(by='Column A', column='Column B', stacked=True)`, but, as the docs say, 'by' will create an histogram by each unique value in the column specified.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you want this:

```
df.pivot(columns="Column A")["Column B"].plot(kind="hist", stacked=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
# taking count since histogram anyway represents the frequencies in each bin.
grp = df.groupby("col_A").agg("count")
plt.hist([grp.index, grp.values.reshape(3,)], bins=3, range=(1,6), stacked=True, color = ['r','g'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you @Priya, but the accepted answer does the job in a very simple manner. On a side note: it would prove very helpful if you'd explained why you're reshaping the group and defining 3 bins.

Comment: Thanks!... The reshaping is needed to make the `grp. values` and `grp. index` shapes compatible and using 3 bins because the count values range between 1 to 2.